# Django: Saving multiple models from ChoiceFiled

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In the Django ModelAdmin Change page I have one InlineModelAdmin (TabularInline) to edit models on the same page as a parent model. There is a ChoiceField in the table for selecting one model in each row. Each model is identified by unique string in this field (e.g. primary key).

There are a lot of items in the ChoiceField (more than thousand) and I want to add many of them at the same time and I don't want to do this manualy for each item. So I defined groups containing preselected items and displayed them in the ChoiceField at the end of list.

Now, I want to save all items from group which I choose in ChoiceField at the end of list and also keep possibility to save one of them. Is there way, how can I do this?

Comment: override the form_save method.

Comment: @Bipul Jain ModelForm.clean() method is called before ModelForm.save() method and must return only one instance of model. As I said, I have group which contains multiple number of models.